# ActiveRecord::Persistence#update ignoring one attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am trying to update a couple of attributes in my `ticket` model, but am stumped as the [ActiveRecord::Persistence#update](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update) method ignores one of the attributes, and updates the other attributes passed in the hash.

```
ticket_params = {"total_quantity"=>"0", "status"=>"refunded"}
ticket.update(ticket_params)
```

Generates the following update query:

```
UPDATE `tickets` SET `status` = 'refunded', `updated_at` = '2015-03-20 21:01:48.145401' WHERE `tickets`.`id` = 307865
```

Same behavior happens when I have 3 attributes in the hash.

```
ticket_params = {"total_quantity"=>0, "status"=>"refunded", billing_name: "TT"}
t.update(ticket_params)
```

The generated update query:

```
UPDATE `tickets` SET `status` = 'paid', `billing_name` = 'TT', `updated_at` = '2015-03-20 21:04:47.893160' WHERE `tickets`.`id` = 307865
```

All these params are marked as required and permitted. Can't find anything special about `total_quantity` attribute anywhere in the code or in the db.

From `db/schema.rb` : `t.integer  "total_quantity",                limit: 4`

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to @creativereason for the comments below. Output while trying to update total_quantity directly:

```
ticket.total_quantity
> 5
ticket.total_quantity = 6
> 6
ticket.total_quantity
> 6
ticket.save
> true
ticket.total_quantity
> 5
```

**FINAL UPDATE:**
There was a `before_validation` callback which was setting the total_quantity back to the original value.

Comment: What's the existing value for total quantity? Curios since Rails ignore unchanged values in ActiveRecord. Also does your total_quantity have a default value in the db?

Comment: In this case, it is 5. Tried with different values for total quantity; same behavior. There is no default for total quantity in the table.

Comment: In one example you have quotes around 0 and the other you don't, but it doesn't seem to save either way. Can you provide example of your model? Just wondering if there is anything with attribute security (but that should throw a `ForbiddenAttributesError` error but apparently isn't)..  What rails 4 version? 

Does the attribute set when using a normal `ticket.total_quantity = 0`?

Comment: `ticket.total_quantity = 0; ticket.save` does not save :-) `Rails 4.2.0`

Comment: does `ticket.total_quantity` display the current value of the attribute? 
What happens in the console when you set it and then retrieve it (before save)? `ticket.total_quantity = 0` `ticket.total_quantity`

Comment: Feel like we probably need to see the model, do you have any callbacks?

Comment: Thanks for that! There is a `before_validation` callback that is setting the total quantity back to original value :-D Please add an answer to this question; I will accept it.

Comment: Done. Glad that was the comment that helped :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double check to make sure you aren't using any callbacks... A `before_save` or similar callback *might* be keeping it set to the original value and you wouldn't see that message.